# How to send data through a form for processing and prevent the page from refreshing?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, django-forms

I am working on my first django project and I encountered a problem that I have no idea how to solve it. I have tried various code samples but unsuccessfully.
I got stuck with the following problem:
I have a form which looks like the following:

```
<form action="{% url 'cart-add' %}" method="GET" id="myform">
     {% csrf_token %}
        <label>
          <input type="hidden" name="{{ product.pk }}">
          <input type="number" max="{{ product.quantity }}" min="1" name="quantity" value="1">
          <button type="submit" value="">Add to chart</button>
        </label>
</form>
```

When I hit the submit button, the handler, by default, throw me to the cart page, where data is being proccessed.
For a better user experience, I want when somebody click "add to cart" button, to not be thrown to another page. For this, I have tried several JQuery and javascript code snippets that I found on internet. It is still not working properly.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myform').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://localhost:8080/product_details/" + {{product.pk}},
            type: "GET",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $("#myform").html(data);
            },
            error: function (jXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The above code is the final result, but it is still not working.
NOTE: When I look into page source on browser, the following script does not appear on the page in the `<script> </script>` block.

I ran out of ideas (not that I had many)

If somebody can help me, I will much appreciate it!

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: In your template - are you putting the JS within the script tags, or do you have a script tag pointing to a `.js` file (like so: `<script src="your_file.js" />`).

The difference here is that you will have to also setup your Django static-files (as JS, CSS & Media are static-files).

Comment: Hey Nicky. No, there's no src file. The code is on the product_detail.html, where it is displayed. I have the scripts from bootstrap JS and some other scripts that I use from static files, but this one is written on the page.

Answer (score 0):

The "action" attribute in your form tells you where to redirect upon submitting the form:

```
form action="{% url 'cart-add' %}"
```

You can set the action attribute to:

```
action=""
```

and it should not redirect any more or you can set to redirect to the same page.